# How do i add an "onclick" to a radio button?

Tags: onclick, radio-button

So I've only started coding recently and I've been trying to replicate something i saw from a website a while back.
  I have an application form, where there are 5 questions referring to a qualification. however, people may have more than one qualification, right? So I've added 2 sets of these 5 questions, and i would like to add a radio button that when you click, it adds another set of 5 questions to the page. Anyone know how i can do this?
  

I know this might sound really simple, but like I said, I'm very new to coding and would really appreciate any help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could already set up the next 5 questions and set them to `display: none;` but have a button that adds a class that displays them using jquery. [jquery website - addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: right idea but instead of adding a class to display you probably should have a class on them to display:none and then you just have to remove none from the ones you want to display. You should also have a class attached to the radio buttons and use $(.hideShowRadio).on("click", function(){}) for the handler

Comment: Many thanks to both of you. I've been pulling my hair out over this for ages, but finished it within 5 minutes once i read this!